# Rmarkdown html report too big. How to save data to external file to lighten the html file?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, markdown, dt

Hello :) Sorry for lame questions, I'm just starting my journey with coding ;)

I wrote some scripts in rmarkdown, using macroeconomic data from World Bank, Eurostat, OECD, etc. Raport is generated to html file, contains a lot of interactive tables made with DT package and sometimes plots with dygraphs. Everythings is working fine, but... the file is too big, it can get even 70 mb and it takes very long to load the tables.

So the question is, is there any possible way to get the data outside the html file and store them in external file/files to lighten the html file? I know that i could do it with shiny, already done it, but i need a standalone file (or more files) without running RStudio in the background.
If I have to learn something outside the R, I can do it, just please give me some ideas or hints. Thank You :)

Answer (score 2):

sounds possible but you will need to know a little javascript & ajax (there are numerous videos about calling standalone data, take it easy). Hope that writing a javascript to call a standalone csv file and embeding the script to your html are going to fix your problem

Comment: Thank You :) Looks very promising :) Will take a little bit of learning, but I'll do it one way or another :D

Comment: just to add further `rmarkdown` puts the data in json format inside script tags. so what you need to do is export those sections using some `bash` script, and then write a js function to reimport them.